# Swift + Sprite Kit Touch Detection

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am just wondering how to remove an SKSprite Node from the scene. This is what I have so far:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    /* Called when a touch begins */


    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        let location = (touch as UITouch).locationInNode(self)
        if let theName = self.nodeAtPoint(location).name {
            if theName == "monster" {

                monster! .removeFromParent()



            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am creating lots of these monsters on the screen but when I tap on one of them it doesn't do anything. If I trying adding `println("touched")` it tells me that it has been touched.

Comment: do you give each of your monsters the name "monster"? Have you set userInteractionEnabled to true on all the monsters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do `monster.removeFromParent()` this does not remove the touched node because `monster` is not a reference to the touched node. To remove the touched node you can use the following code:

```
for touch in touches {
    let location = (touch as UITouch).locationInNode(self)
    if let theMonster = self.nodeAtPoint(location) 
        if theMonster.name == "monster" {
            theMonster.removeFromParent()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you keeping track of your monsters? If not please keep track of those by adding these to a Mutable Array. Also add unique name to each sprite.

Then just compare the object with your array and remove that object. Hope this helps.. :)

Comment: How would I do that? My objects keep coming down forever. I have it programmed to say every 0.5 sec set sprite above screen in a random position and then fall down.  Thanks